# Why does my flutter code run twice instead of running once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a flutter project that i expect to run once, but it runs twice instead.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app_2_4/pages/game.dart';
import 'package:my_app_2_4/pages/intro.dart';
import 'package:my_app_2_4/pages/sayac.dart';

void main() {
  print('here we go');
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Intro(),
        '/sayac' : (context) => Sayac(),
        '/game' : (context) => Home(),
      }
  ));
}
```

Here is the output that i got:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM T500 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51184/QLupSSeQTS0=/ws
Syncing files to device SM T500...
I/flutter ( 5976): here we go
I/flutter ( 5976): here we go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build method might get called multiple times and it shouldn't be considered a problem. It's how Flutter works.

As per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget/build.html):
`The framework calls this method when this widget is inserted into the tree in a given BuildContext and when the dependencies of this widget change. [...] This method can potentially be called in every frame and should not have any side effects beyond building a widget.`

Here's a [response from the Flutter team](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57353#issuecomment-629569076) on a similar closed issue.

Comment: The link states about the build method not about the main method!!

Comment: i see but print function is before the runApp. It is not inside of any build method. Is void main() function considered as build method?

Comment: Initially, the code gets bundled and the main method is called, then the code/application is synced to the emulator or device and again the main function is called to start the application.

Comment: @yunus No the main() is different from the build method. However, the reason it gets called twice or more is similar to the multiple calls of build method